# DLNM: centering of continuous variables

Tags: r, time-series, nonlinear-regression, distributed-lag

DLNM centers the basis variables at the mean of the continuous variables.  The value at which the variable is centered becomes the reference.  How do I change the centered/reference value?  As per the paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3191524/ , cenvalue option enables the change in centered value and summary() gives the details of centered value but I don't see it when I run it.  How can I see what the centered value is?  How can I change the reference value?  A sample code is given below.

```
library(dlnm)
basis.temp <− crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp, vartype = "bs",
                         vardegree = 3, vardf = 6, cenvalue = 25, lagdf = 5, maxlag = 30)
summary(basis.temp)
```